# Hyperlink a static image with a URL from a specific field

Tags: excel, vba, image, dynamic, hyperlink

I'm trying to complete a multi-step vba function based on a cell that will dynamically change based on another field being updated.  To simplify:

- Cell B12 on Sheet 1 = url (defined name is "Company_URL") that changes when B11 is updated on Sheet 1.
- As this URL changes, I want to hyperlink an image in Sheet 2 with that url.
- the image is titled "app"

```vb
Sub HyperLink()

    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
    Anchor:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Shapes("app"), _
    Address:="http://" & Range("Company_URL").Value

End Sub
```

This is erroring indicating the item with the specified name isn't found.

I'd also like to add an image (called "image2") into Sheet2!c12:e14 if Sheet1!b11 = "john" "jim" "doug".

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that excel isn't recognizing the picture by the name "app". Either you have to manually select the picture by index or you have to name it as "app" yourself before you can select it.

```
Sub HyperLink()

    'Name the shape at index 1 as "app"
    Sheets(2).Shapes(1).Name = "app"

    'Link to the shape previously named "app"
    Sheets(2).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets(2).Shapes("app"), _
        Address:=Sheets(1).Range("B12").Value2

End Sub
```

Comment: I was having issues using this on a different sheet, I believe it's because of the Shape index.  Is there a better way to call the specific shape?  There are multiple shapes on this sheet and the code is running but not hyperlinking to the correct shape.  I've tried each number until I get an out of bounds and there is one that I get a run time error "70" on.  Not sure if that is the one.  Either way, it's working now but I can't identify the correct shape to call in the code despite the naming convention you identified.

Comment: I figured it out.  I opened a new sheet, created the shape i wanted to index and then ran the macro, then copied over the information from the previous sheet.   Thank you very much for your help, Marcucciboy2!